# Why does System.out.println(map.put(1,"test")) print null value?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
class Test3 {  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        Map<Integer, String> aa = new HashMap();
        System.out.println(aa.put(1, "test"));
    }  

}
```

whenever I execute this statement it prints null value. I want to know why it printing the null value. What is happening?

Comment: Why don't you read the Javadoc of `Map.put`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Javadoc of `Map.put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-):

> ```
> V put(K key,
>   V value)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Returns**: the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key.

The map is empty before the call to `put`, so "there was no mapping for key", so `null` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

implementation of put is something like below

```
@Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return putImpl(key, value);
    }
```

If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced. else null will return because there is no mapping.

Comment: While correct I prefer to read the documentation over the implementation in the cases where the documentation provides the information we seek. I believe that that is the case here.